# Clear description of Timsort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, timsort

I have been Googleing and reading about Timsort on Wikipedia, and other resources.
Yet, I don't have a clear Idea of what is Timsort doing.
Can anyone describe the algorithm, or provide me with some documentations containing a clear description?

Comment: Also see an implementation of timsort here: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c

Comment: I already have seen that, but it is not very clear to me! :(

Comment: @programmingIsFun:  You say that you've read Tim Peter's explanation and the Wikipedia entry but they were not clear to you.  Can you unpack that into a more specific line of questioning?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I downvoted because a question along the lines of "I just don't get it" is not constructive.  He's essentially asking for a targeted tutorial, but gives us little information about what he *does* and *doesn't* understand.  I think any useful answer to this question will be too specific to the OP's current understanding of computer science.  I also think a useful answer would end up being a chapter length description since the shorter descriptions on the web do not suffice.

Comment: I think it may be a language barrier unfortunately :( Not much one can do there.

Comment: FWIW, here's an implementation of Timsort in Python/Cython (at your option): http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/sort-comparison/  You can generate either a .py or a .pyx using m4 on the same .m4 file - kind of like the C preprocessor in a way.

Comment: I don't think this needs to be downvoted, but it would be helpful for the person posing the question to be more specific about which part of the algorithm is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

The Timsort algorithm is a merge sort algorithm specifically designed for sorting lists of data that are already partially sorted. It is a stable sort, meaning that it preserves the relative order of elements that are equal to each other.

The algorithm begins by dividing the list of data into two halves. It then merges the two halves together, using a merge sort algorithm, to create a new, sorted list. This process is repeated until the list of data is sorted.

The Timsort algorithm is described in more detail in the following document:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort